# assign variable to the return of a case statement Elixir

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, can I do

```
foo = ""
foo = case bar do
        _ -> "foo is now this value"
      end
```

i.e assigning whatever the return of a case statement is to a variable in Elixir ( I know you can do the same with an if statement) ? If I can is this bad practise?

Comment: you can assign the return of a case statement, but in this example you are not really using the case statement. this is basically the same as `foo = "foo is now this value"` whatever the value for `bar` is. what concrete example are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sabiwara to put it short I pattern match according to first element in a queue , but depending on the outcome of what happens in my case, after the case statement i will either drop first task from queue or leave it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `case` statement can be assigned to a variable, and its value will be the one of the clause that is matching.

Here is an example inspired by the use case you described in the comment:

```
list =
  case list do
    [{:foo, _} | rest] -> rest
    _ -> list
  end
```

`list` will be reassigned no matter what, so if you want to keep it untouched you need to have an explicit clause returning the original value. Without the `_ -> list` clause, a `CaseClauseError` would be raised.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely legit and is not a bad practice by any means. Furthermore, each and every statement in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) does return a value, because everything is a macro.

This is widely used everywhere and even when one omits the returned value for side effects only, it gets indeed returned from any call.

[`Kernel.if/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#if/2) is as well a macro, that gets compiled into [`Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#case/2) [behind the scene](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.2/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3329-L3332).

Literally, anything, including but not limited to [`Kernel.def/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#def/2) returns a value; `def/2` returns AST that gets then compiled into BEAM for ErlangVM.

The most common example of this would be [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2), also ironically called *poor man debug*, which might be dropped in anywhere in the code because it returns back what it receives as a first parameter.

```rb
IO.inspect({:foo, 42})
# ... some std output

#⇒{:foo, 42}
```